# Is there a silent logout option in angular-oauth2-oidc?

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, ionic4, openid-connect, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am using angular-oauth2-oidc in my ionic 4 app and wanted to know if there is a way to implement silent logout since I couldn't find it in the angular-oauth2-oidc docs.

Comment: What do you mean with"silent" logout? What makes it different from calling the `logOut()`method?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen - What I meant to say was when the token expires the app should log out automatically, instead I'm seeing requests with 401 errors. Should I explicitly call logOut() on 401 error in an interceptor?

Answer (score 1):

If you call `.logout(...)`

- either while `logoutUrl` isfalsy (it's an OAuthConfig option I believe);
- or with `false` as a parameter for `noRedirectToLogoutUrl`

then [the library won't redirect you to the identity server](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/d95d7da788e2c1390346c66de62dc31f10d2b852/projects/lib/src/oauth-service.ts#L2521-L2526) making it a "silent" (*but client-side only*!) logout.

There's nothing in the library for then also logging out on the identity server, for example I don't think "backchannel logout" is supported. You'd have to write something for that yourself.